# I need basic help with custom post types

Tags: custom-post-types

Basically here's my project:

I have to create a back-end wordpress gui user input section. The user will enter details about their projects like name, location, what it is, some other details. A page will display the top 9 recent or so in a 3x3 grid. There will be a search bar to search projects for related tags.

I have currently:

- used functions.php to setup my post
  type and it works
- used simple forms plugin to create
  forms on the add new page

Background: I am a pretty entry level person in wordpress, and slightly overwhelmed right now. But, it's slowly coming together. Any input on structure or anything would be appreciated.

Update: I have created the forms, but I need to know what to put in the single-projects.php to display the content from the forms.

Thank you so much

Comment: Can you be more specific? Here are a couple of questions to start: Should the above example data exist as a taxonomy or custom field? Is the user adding information through the admin panel or front end? My guess is that you are trying to add taxonomies that will be accessed through the admin panel; if so, try the codex: [taxonomies](http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies) and [WordPress Taxonomy](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Taxonomy)

Comment: I created a new question at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9658/i-am-trying-to-create-a-back-end-wordpress-content-submission-using-custom-post-t

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi **@jeff:**

This list of plugins should give you what you need:

- [**Custom Post Type Plugins**](http://files.meetup.com/1280797/custom-post-types-for-wordpress-atlwp-2010-10-24.html#links)

#### UPDATE

Try this plugin as it lets you set up fields for the user to enter into:

- [**Simple Fields**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-fields/)

Comment: Appreciate it, but I'm pretty much lost. I have the post type setup and I have a basic loop for my /projects and when I click on it, it will go to /projects/theproject.

Comment: I also managed to get a text box to work and update, but I'm just lost and I need something to go over everything slowly because right now I'm having to dive into this project of mine to set it up.

Comment: Simple fields did it all great. Thanks. Now (sorry for ignorance here) how do I get the data back to display on a page?

Comment: @jeff - Might be a good to **[ask a new question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)** for that? Be sure to ask your questions with a title that helps people understand exactly what you need at a glance. Also, don't forget to reward the people who help you with up-votes and by accepting answers.

Comment: can't upvote yet

Comment: @Jeff - No problem, and you will be soon. FYI for the newbie, selecting *"best answer"* and using up-votes is how to *"tip"* the wait staff here. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd take a look at one of these plugins:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-field-template/

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-fields/

I use Custom Field Templates (CFT) on almost every project I do, specifically so that I can assign (better looking) Custom Fields to my defined Custom Post Types.  There's a number of tutorials around the web on how to get data back out of WP once its been stored as a Custom Field...these plugins just make it prettier/easier on the administrative side.

Hope that helps...

Comment: Hey I appreciate this. I'm entry level and my employer tasked me with creating a project submission where users can add projects with details. I'm not really sure how everything works (I'm very new to WP). I have tried reading a number of tutorials but they just seem like garble right now. But I can code in php and follow some of it. I just have a hard time with WP because I really didn't write it to understand.