# create a back-end wordpress content submission using custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, taxonomy, user-access

I have a previously created thread here, but was recommended to make a new one:
[I need basic help with custom post types](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9536/i-need-basic-help-with-custom-post-types)

Basically here's my project:

I have to create a back-end wordpress gui user input section. The user will enter details about their projects like name, location, what it is, some other details. A page will display the top 9 recent or so in a 3x3 grid. There will be a search bar to search projects for related tags.

I need to set it up where only certain user accounts can access this post type to upload projects.

I have currently:

- used functions.php to setup my post
  type and it works
- used simple forms plugin to create
  forms on the add new page

Background: I am a pretty entry level person in wordpress, and slightly overwhelmed right now. But, it's slowly coming together. Any input on structure or anything would be appreciated.

Update: I have created the forms, but I need to know what to put in the single-projects.php to display the content from the forms.

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several user access plugins available, including one called [Members](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/members/).

The settings panel for the Members plugin is in Settings >> Members Components. From there you can enable what you want. To edit roles you have to enable the Edit Roles component, then go to Users >> Roles. Click on the role you want to edit. You will see a list of all available capabilities with the ones that are enabled checked and in bold. There are six text boxes at the bottom of the page allowing you to add six capabilities at a time. Just type in the names there and they will be added to that role and to the list of capabilities. To add them to another role, just select them in the list.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll look into it. Do you know where in the plugin you can define what post type a user group can edit?

Comment: Basically, I'm trying to create a role that can only view "projects" and edit their own project.

Comment: That sounds like the Authors role. Authors can only edit their own posts, so you might not need the aforementioned plugin.

Comment: I don't want them to be able to edit other post types, just the Projects. Would the plugin manage this, or where in the code would I find this? I have been looking through the codex with no luck so far.

Comment: You can always add capabilities if the current ones aren't suited to your need. In your case, I would call it edit_projects, create_projects, etc, and add it to whichever role you want. You could also make a new role and add them to it, once you enable the New Roles component.

Comment: Sorry for the "noob" questions, but where and how do you add capabilities and give them permissions to post types

Comment: Go to Users >> Roles, and then click on the role you want to add it to. You will see six text boxes at the bottom of the page. Just type in the names there and they will be added to that role and to the list of capabilities. To add them to another role, just select them in the list.

Comment: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/46885/project.png

I did this, but how do I only make "projects" show up on left side for authors using capabilities? I don't want other post types showing. 

I basically only want "profile" and "projects" to show.

Comment: Why don't you make a second user account with the role that you are working on, and see how it looks. To restrict it further just add, for instance, "admin_quotes" or something like that, so that only people with that will be able to administer quotes. That is easier than having three separate ones for create, edit, and delete, but it depends on the situation.

Comment: Ok but where and how do I actually give "admin_quotes" functionality. I created it in the textbox.

Comment: Make sure it is selected from the list above the textboxes, then program your plugin to check for the capability. Looking at the picture you linked above, I see that you have edit_projects, create_projects, delete_projects, projects, and project. While the first 3 are obvious, what are the last two for?

Comment: Ok and I'm assuming this snipet of code in the readme relates to it?

<?php if ( function_exists( 'current_user_has_role' ) && current_user_has_role( 'editor' ) ) { ?>
 Only users with the editor role can see this content.
<?php } ?>

Comment: if ( function_exists( 'members_check_for_cap' ) && members_check_for_cap( 'some_cap' ) ) {
 /* Do something if any role has the 'some_cap' capability. */
else {
 /* Do something for people without the plugin. */
}

Comment: "projects" and "project" were there automatically for some reason? I'm actually looking as to why right now, but I'm just assuming it's because of a plugin.

Comment: Where did you find `members_check_for_cap`? I think it is `current_user_can( 'edit_posts' )`

Comment: The readme:
In WordPress, you can use the current_user_can() function to check if the current user has a particular capability. Since you don't know whether a user has this plugin installed, you might want to check first.

The members_check_for_cap() function (only use in admin) checks if any role has a particular capability. This can be useful in setting up something like admin menus. For example, you can set up a theme settings menu for users that have the edit_themes capability. But, if this plugin is installed and a user has the edit_my_theme capability, that'll be used instead.

Comment: There's a break down in the readme.html with an example, but I guess current_user_can( 'create_project' ) can work instead? Now I just need to find where the left nav menu items are to only show certain ones if you have the capabilities. I really appreciate the help by the way.

Comment: Can you give me the name of the plugin that adds the quotes menu item?

Comment: quotes is just a custom post type we made, but you can make it in custom post type ui

Comment: How did you make it, please post the snippet or plugin name you used so I can check it out.

Comment: That's what custom post types look like. And this is the plug-in. You can also just define it in functions.php

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-post-type-ui

Comment: This is **not** a discussion forum.  Please keep real-time back-and-forth discussions in the chat room ("StopPress" accessible from the right sidebar) or use the WordPress.org support forums!

Comment: Let's take it to StopPress.

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6

Comment: @EAMann I can't connect to the chatroom, yet and this information I need to obtain. What am I supposed to do? I do not have enough reputation here.

Comment: You now have 23 ... feel free to chat.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar project to create a grid output in the front end. I guess I also made 3 by 3 table. I used the custom fields. I used the plugin called More fields to design the back end the way I wanted it...and then I edited the single.php file of my theme.

I basically used HTML and php (basic). I made 3 by 3 table and then called the custom field values in them. It was quiet an efficient way to display. And regarding allowing certain users to access it...I guess you can install multiple plugins to filter the users.